# Extract IP:PORT from a curl output

Tags: linux, awk, grep, xml

I want to get list ip:port from the curl output of

```
curl https://www.gametracker.com/search/?sort=5&order=ASC
```

I cannot post the whole output as it is very big, just posting the part from where we need to extract IP:PORT

```
                                <a href="/search/?sort=4&amp;order=ASC">Loc</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_h">
                                <a href="/search/?sort=5&amp;order=DESC">IP:Port</a>▼
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_h">
                                <a href="/search/?sort=6&amp;order=ASC">Server Map</a>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                                20.
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="/search/swat4/">
                                        <img src="/images/game_icons16/swat4.png" alt="SWAT4"/>
                                </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <a  href="/server_info/1.12.237.104:10520/">



                                        tejingduiba FR0.67 TEST


                                </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                0/16
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="/search/_all/CN/">
                                        <img src="/images/flags/cn.gif" alt="" class="item_16x11"/>
                                </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <span class="ip">1.12.237.104</span><span class="port">:10520</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                Red Library Offices
```

I just need to extract all these values `1.12.237.104:10520` so its like `IP:PORT`

How can this be done using awk, grep or any other method?

Comment: Have you seen and tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604395/grep-ip-and-port-from-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is to get the values of all pairs of `span` nodes with `class` attributes `ip` and `port`. These occur as pairs under `td` nodes in the HTML.

The first issue is that the output from `curl` is not clean XML.  This can be fixed by reformating the HTML into XML using `xmlstarlet`:

```bash
curl --silent 'URL' | xmlstarlet format --html
```

With the document in XML, we can now find all `td` nodes we're interested in.  These are the `td` nodes that have a child `span` node with a `class` attribute of `ip` (we assume that there is another sibling `span` node with a `class` attribute of `port`).  For each such `td` node, we concatenate the values of the node's `span` child nodes.

```bash
curl --silent 'URL' | xmlstarlet format --html |
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//_:td[_:span[@class="ip"]]' \
    --value-of 'concat(_:span[@class="ip"], _:span[@class="port"])' -nl
```

The funky-looking `_:` before each node name is due to the document using a default namespace.

Given the current state of the game server, this outputs

```
1.12.237.104:10520
1.14.139.78:14567
1.15.235.182:27102
1.117.83.171:27025
1.117.83.171:27026
2.56.96.145:27960
2.56.99.56:9987
2.56.213.77:27015
2.204.29.39:27015
2.204.29.39:27016
3.0.10.0:28960
3.0.242.157:28960
3.6.230.224:27015
3.17.155.136:19274
3.28.115.189:27015
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use feature qw/say/;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    autocheck => 0,
    quiet => 1,
);
$m->agent_alias("Linux Mozilla");

$m->get("https://www.gametracker.com/search/?sort=5&order=ASC");
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $m->content );
my @arr = $tree->findvalues( '//td/span[@class="ip"]/text() | //td/span[@class="port"]/text()' );
for (my $i=0; $i<$#arr; $i+=2) {
    say $arr[$i] . $arr[$i+1];
}
```

### Output

```
1.12.237.104:10520
1.14.139.78:14567
1.15.235.182:27102
1.117.83.171:27025
1.117.83.171:27026
2.56.96.145:27960
2.56.99.56:9987
2.56.213.77:27015
2.204.29.39:27015
2.204.29.39:27016
3.0.10.0:28960
3.0.242.157:28960
3.6.230.224:27015
3.17.155.136:19274
3.28.115.189:27015
```

Comment: How do you know that the `span[@class="ip"]` values pair up correctly with the `span[@class="port"]` values? I mean, they _do_, but you actually don't relate the `//td/span[@class="ip"]` set to the `//td/span[@class="port"]` set. Are you guaranteed to get them in (the same) order?

Comment: (Cont.) ... this is why I matched the relevant `td` nodes first. However, I don't really know if I _had_ to do that, and your answer seems to suggest that I didn't, which is interesting to know. But it may require knowing/assuming that each relevant `td` node actually had a complete pair of `span` nodes with the required attribute values.